# not able to find /var/lib/awx/projects directory after installing awx version 19 and more(19.2.2)

Tags: ansible-awx

I installed AWX version 19.2.2 on my machine which is ubuntu 18.04.5
It got installed without any error and I can see the AWX web page at https://my machine ip:8043/#/login. I installed AWX using docker. for AWX port 8043 is opened. From AWX page I tried running playbooks but i am not able to see the /var/lib/awx/projects/ directory in my machine after successfully installing AWX.Also i tried changing the path of the directory by changing the path in /awx/awx/settings/defaults.py.i changed path to /home/ubuntu/exmp/awx/projects.but no use.
so can anyone help me regarding this playbook directory to appear in my machine